# Setting up OpenCV to use with Shotwell

Tags: opencv, shotwell

I'm wanting to try the beta/unstable version 0.29.3 of Shotwell that contains the feature facial recognition. https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/06/new-shotwell-update-face-detection
But I don't have the "know how" to install OpenCV so that it works with Shotwell.  Is there someone that can tell me how to do this?

I'm running LinuxMint 19 (Ubuntu 18.04).

Comment: See askubuntu.com/a/1145778/898365 (It is possible to use this feature when on the unstable branch of the Flatpak version of Shotwell, but it still has basically the same functionality since 2011 - it can only detect faces in one photograph at a time, and sometimes it might think your curtain or fridge is a face - but at least you have the ability to manually draw a box around a face, which is good progress.)

Answer (score 1):

To install OpenCV use:

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```